# App Inventor WebViewer won't open in fullscreen

Tags: app-inventor

I have added my own html file to the webviewer so it can display it inside the app. I have used the webviewer component like this:

[image: Blocks]

but I'm getting this result:

[image: Screenshot]

So the point is, I want to make this view from "screenshot" at fullscreen. What did I do wrong or what did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

In the designer set the height and the width of the webviewer component to `fill parent`.
See also [How to read a HTML page stored as asset inside of App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2htmlread)